# How to show navigation bar on page which doesn't belong to this bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

edit: **SOLUTION**
i used package [custom_navigator](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigator)

In navigation bar I have 2 pages to redirect, but I want to navigate to third page and still want to see navigation bar (this one with 2 pages) there.

Is it possible to do? Do I have to make my own navigation bar for this page?

```
class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BarState createState() => BarState();
}

class BarState extends State<Bar> {
  int tabIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pages = [
    FirstPage(),
    SecondPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              iconSize: 25,
              elevation: 4.0,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                barItem(Icons.message),
                barItem(Icons.camera_enhance),
                barItem(Icons.person),
              ],
              currentIndex: tabIndex,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  tabIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
          )),
      body: Container(
        child: pages.elementAt(tabIndex),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is what i try:

```
List<Widget> pages = [
    Container( 
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: state
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SecondPage(),
    ThirdPage()
  ];

  state() {
    tabIndex = 2;
    setState(() {
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you add more details, code blocks for example?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this... you have a flow that has three pages and you want the navigation bar to be shared between page 2 and page 3?

Comment: yes, i want to navigate to the ThirdPage with button and still have there (on ThirdPage) the same navigation bar for page first and two

Comment: i updated quest

Comment: Does it need to be sticky? As in you don't want it to move when you navigate or do you not mind if it animates?

Comment: all i want is accessing 3rd page and still got navigation bar there, I created own bar as widget with navigator but it wasnt as smooth as real bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, if you don't mind it animating would be to init an `AppBar` in your navigator and pass it to the pages and they would use it in there scaffold.

```dart
class MyFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFlow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyFlowState createState() => _MyFlowState();
}

class _MyFlowState extends State<MyFlow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBar = AppBar();

    return Navigator(
      onPopPage: (route, result) => true,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(child: PageOne(appBar: appBar)),
        MaterialPage(child: PageTwo(appBar: appBar)),
        MaterialPage(child: PageThree(appBar: appBar)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageOne({Key? key, required this.appBar}) : super(key: key);

  final AppBar appBar;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain this solution to me? when i run MyFlow there is empty screen

Comment: Well I don't have enough context of the problem. This was just throwing a dart, pun intended, blind. How are you "running" it? Typically you would push on `MyFlow` from another navigator and when the flow is done you would have a callback to let the thing that pushed, pop it.